# zabbix agent return powershell value

Tags: powershell, zabbix

i try to monitor cpu server with zabbix agent, my item key is not supported on zabbix, i tried this item key :

```
#system.run["powershell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File C:\zabbix\conf\CPU_%.ps1"] 

#system.run["C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -File C:\zabbix\conf\CPU_%.ps1",]
```

i want to know which item key in zabbix is supported ?

thanks for any response

Comment: Why not simple use percounter? "perf_counter[\Processor(_Total)\% User Time]
perf_counter[\Processor(_Total)\% Privileged Time]
perf_counter[\System\Processor Queue Length]
perf_counter[\Paging File(_Total)\% Usage]"

Comment: Did you set `EnableRemoteCommands=1` on the Agent?
This is disabled by default but needed for system.run key to work. Also: what are the logs saying?

Answer (score 0):

Add the line to zabbix_agentd.conf or zabbix_agent2.conf:

> UserParameter=CPU[*], powershell -File "C:\zabbix\conf\CPU_%.ps1"

Add element Zabbix Agent (Active) with key CPU[]